# character left angular not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a textarea like this in my angular view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Descrição</label>
    <textarea name="area" ng-minlength="30" class="form-control" ng-model="produtos.descricao" id="descricao" type="text" placeholder="descricao"></textarea>
    <span ng-if="check()">Caracteres restantes: {{produtos.descricao.length}}</span>
</div>
```

and in my controller i have:

```
$scope.produtos = [];
$scope.minLength = 30;
console.log($scope.minLength);

$scope.check = function(){
    return ($scope.produtos.descricao.length < 30);
}
```

if it is true the check shouldn't ng if work?

Comment: `$scope.produtos` is an array, so it can't have an attribute called `descricao`, at least according to the code you posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to access `$scope.produtos.descricao.length`. But during initialization you have initialized `$scope.produtos = []`. There is no property in `$scope.produtos` named as `descricao`. So when you do `descricao.length` it will throw an error and code won't execute successfully. You can check the error in developer console. That is why the function `check()` is not executing and errors out. And ng-if is not working.

Comment: can i make you a fast out-topic question?

Comment: @FilipeCosta Sure

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confusing. I am not sure if `$scope.produtos` is an array or an object. But i think i understand what you need here, you need to show `<span ng-if="check()">Caracteres restantes: {{produtos.descricao.length}}</span>` when characters in the text box are less than 30. Consider the code below to resolve your problem.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Descrição</label>
  <textarea name="area" ng-minlength="30" class="form-control" ng-model="something" id="descricao" type="text" placeholder="descricao"></textarea>
  <span ng-if="something.length<30">Caracteres restantes: {{something.length}}</span></div>
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: well my $scope.produtos is a array of object, i used produtos.descricao.length to get the length of the description of the product, the property